# Why event listener cannot read property?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

I am new at JavaScript and I'm trying some events. The goal here is to click at some text and display a message. I have a `p` element in my html like this:

```
<p id="tab">Click me</p>
```

At the .js file I tried this and nothing happened. The console yells me this:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

```js
var demo=document.getElementById("tab");

demo.addEventListener("click", go);

function go(){
    alert("Hey");
}
```

The code above resides in a separate .js file

Comment: Place your script just before you close the `body` tag

Comment: If your script is in the `head` section, then before your `p` is in `DOM`, the script executes..hence the error

Comment: Make sure you are writing the correct path to your file, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I did this to add the script at the head section
<script src="exp.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Code shown below works in IE, Chrome and FireFox - I didn't test this in  
any other browser.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitPage() {
        var demo = document.getElementById("tab");
        demo.addEventListener("click", go);
        function go() {
            console.log("Hey");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="InitPage();">
    <p id="tab">Click me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script seems to be working fine. Make sure it runs after the element is created by adding in it the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) handler, or placing it just before `</body>`

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("tab");

demo.addEventListener("click", go);

function go() {
  console.log("Hey");
}
```

```html
<p id="tab">Click me</p>
```

Comment: If you inspect this webpage and click the demo in my answer, you'll get it. That's because the code in stack snippet is wrapped in `onload` event handler and runs after elements are created. In your case, your code `document.getElementById("tab");` is running before the element is actually created so it returns `null`

Comment: I just wrote the same code inside a window.onload = function(){ // the old script here} and it worked fine. Why?

Comment: @CélioRodrigues as i told earlier, previously your code was executing before the `tab` element was created... script is executed as soon as browser encounter them... if you have the script before the element, it gets executed before the element is created. `onload` event is fired when the entire document is created and all resources are loaded. So it works

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much